# The name 'ScriptManager' does not exist in the current context

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

I copied some code to solve a problem with running JavaScript after an AJAX postback in ASP.Net. Unfortunately the new code gave me the following error when doing a build:

```
The name 'ScriptManager' does not exist in the current context
```

Now I've used the ScriptManager before, so why would it be giving me problems now? Isn't it available on all ASP.Net pages? I have a script manager on my master page after all...

Answer (score 19):

If you are not getting `ScriptManager` in `System.Web.UI` then add a reference for `System.Web.Extensions`. (Go to solutions explorer -> right click on project -> Select add reference -> in *.Net* tab select `System.Web.Extensions` and click <kbd>OK</kbd>). This worked for me when I was getting that error even after using `System.Web.UI`.

Answer (score 17):

I suppose there could be a number of things wrong that would generate this error message. But for me, all I had to do was add the following using to the top of my code-behind file:

```
using System.Web.UI;
```

I hope this helps someone out there, maybe it'll save you some time.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I read other answers that kept saying to use System.Data, which I already had and wasn't working.