# The name 'ScriptManager' does not exist in the current context when calling JS function in Codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, namespaces

I need to call a JS function via codebehind when its no postback on a site. 
I've added my script before the closing `<head>` Tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function StartWidgetTour() {
        //init the tour!
        wWidgetTour.init();

        //finally start the tour! strange but we have to restart.
        wWidgetTour.restart();
    }
</script>
```

My Code looks like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "Widget Tour Start!", "StartWidgetTour()", true);
        //more code that already works
```

When I want to run this code, I get a built error `The name 'ScriptManager' does not exist in the current context`.

I am already using namespace `System.Web` and `System.Web.UI;`. 
The answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941334/the-name-scriptmanager-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context) didn't worked for me.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Add a scriptmanager to the *.aspx page

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```